# Get list of formats in Apache Spark (data sources)

Tags: python, apache-spark, validation, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We need to get the list of formats (read-write) for some config file validations. The formats I am talking about are:

```
spark.read.format('this')

spark.write.format('this')
```

Is there a way to get it as a list? For example

```
formats = spark.sql.utils.getFormats()
print(formats)
```

out:

> ['parquet', 'delta', 'csv', etc]

In documentation it is listed but we need to access programmatically https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CheTesta Edited with an example of what we need, thanks!

Comment: aren't the list of formats static across all recent version?